# NullPointerException al realizar una búsqueda en mi tabla para leer los registros y mostrarlos en un JTable

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un método que me permite buscar todos los registros de mi tabla que tengan ese nombre y también, en ella creo el `DefaultTableModel` y también lo retorno. Esto con el fin de llenar el JTable con registros actualizados.

Al correr el programa recibo el error `NullPointerException`.

**EDIT**

Mi método en mi clase Logica_usuario :

public class Logica_usuario {

```
private ConexionMySQL MySQL = new ConexionMySQL();
private Connection con = MySQL.conectarMySQL();
private String sSQL =   "";
public int totalUsuarios = 0;

public DefaultTableModel buscarRegistro(String buscar) {
DefaultTableModel model = null;

String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Usuario", "Contraseña", "ID Perfil"};
Object [][] registros = new Object[6][6];//6 fila por 6 columnas

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre LIKE '%" + buscar + "%' ORDER BY id_usuario";

// Java 7 try-with-resources
try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
     ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

    int i = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
        registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
        registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
        registros[i][3] = rs.getString("usuario");
        registros[i][4] = rs.getString("contrasena");
        registros[i][5] = rs.getInt("id_perfil");

        totalUsuarios++;
        i++;
    }

    model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: mostrarRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

return model;
```

}

Mi procedimiento en mi clase Ventana_Usuario:

```
void buscarRegistro(String buscar) {
        try {
            logica_usuario = new Logica_usuario();
            DefaultTableModel model;
            model = logica_usuario.buscarRegistro(buscar);
            table.setModel(model);
            setColumnsWidth();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: mostrar(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

Al inicializar el Frame de mi JPanel, le envío `" "` para que me cargue por primera vez el JTable con los títulos de la columna:

```
public Ventana_Usuario() {
        setTitle("Mantenimiento de Usuarios");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 634, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        buscarRegistro("");
```

Pero, al arrancar el programa recibo un `NullPointerException`. Al menos al arrancar el programa y realizar una búsqueda, los resultados se muestran en el JTable, aunque los títulos de las columnas no aparecen.

**EDIT:** agrego StackTrace

StackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ventanas.Ventana_Usuario.buscarRegistro(Ventana_Usuario.java:66)
    at ventanas.Ventana_Usuario.<init>(Ventana_Usuario.java:110)
    at ventanas.Ventana_Usuario$1.run(Ventana_Usuario.java:87)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Ventana_Usuario.java:66

```
table.setModel(model);
```

Ventana_Usuario.java:110

```
buscarRegistro("");
```

Ventana_Usuario.java:87)

```
Ventana_Usuario frame = new Ventana_Usuario();
```

No tengo ni la menor idea de el por qué, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias por todo de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que la variable `logica_usuario` no es nula y `buscar` tampoco lo es?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza logica_usuario es una instancia de mi clase Logica_usuario, el cual contiene toda la lógica de mi programa, incluyendo el método para hacer la busqueda, llenar el JTable y retornarla. Funciona bien si intento buscar una palabra, el JTable se llena con los datos encontrados pero, no muestra los títulos y al arrancar el programa recibo NullPointerException. :(

Comment: Sería mejor que edites la pregunta y coloques tu stacktrace. Si dices que el `NullPointerException` se lanza en la línea `model = logica_usuario.buscarRegistro(buscar);` significa que la variable `logica_usuario` es nula, pero si dices que no lo es, entonces no se puede revisar bien el problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ahora que reviso, no me muestra ningun error en color rojo en la consola, al parecer lo había arreglado antes. Pero si me marca el nullPointerException y el buscador funciona, es decir que la variable que dices si tiene valor. He creado un screenshot para que veas lo que pasa: http://oi68.tinypic.com/20z776s.jpg

Comment: Deberías huir de los "números mágicos" como el que tienes en la línea: `String [] registros = new String[6];`. ¿Porqué crees que el `ResultSet` no va a tener nunca más de 6 filas? ¿Tienes marcada alguna limitación? ¿Tienes pensado que harás cuando muestres la tabla si cargas menos de 6 filas?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza es algo que no había notado, he hecho los cambios que me ha indicado "Awes0meM4n" mas abajo pero, sigo con el problema, ahora el JTable muestra 6 filas en blanco, con nada en su interior. Los títulos de las columnas siguen sin mostrarse. Screenshot: http://oi67.tinypic.com/345llap.jpg

Comment: No uses arreglos para leer data de un `ResultSet`, usa listas. Esto ya se cubrió en otra pregunta que hiciste.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he hecho el cambio pero, todo sigue igual. Screenshot: http://oi67.tinypic.com/t5himd.jpg

Comment: Muestra el stacktrace. Si no, no podemos revisar qué es lo que realmente sucede.

Comment: El `PreparedStatement` lo usas incorrectamente. Este tipo de objeto se usa para precompilar el query y que esté preparado para pasarle parámetros que has establecido en su definición. Pero en tu caso ni estableces parámetros ni por supuesto le pasas ninguno antes de ejecutarla.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he agregado el StackTrace en la publicacion inicial y he agregado las líneas de código que indican el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal implementada tu tabla. Prueba de esta forma:

```
public DefaultTableModel buscarRegistro(String buscar) {
    DefaultTableModel model = null;

    String sSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre LIKE '%" + buscar + "%' ORDER BY id_usuario";

    try (Statement stm = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sSQL)) {
        rs.last();
        int filas = rs.getRow();
        rs.first();

        String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Usuario", "Contraseña", "ID Perfil"};
        Object [][] registros = new Object[filas][titulosColumnas.length];

        int i = 0;
        do {
            registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
            registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
            registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
            registros[i][3] = rs.getString("usuario");
            registros[i][4] = rs.getString("contrasena");
            registros[i][5] = rs.getInt("id_perfil");

            totalUsuarios++;
            i++;
        } while (rs.next());

        model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: mostrarRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    return model;
}
```

Y luego la forma de presentarla con el `JScrollPane` sería:

```
void buscarRegistro(String buscar) {
    try {
        logica_usuario = new Logica_Usuario();
        DefaultTableModel model = logica_usuario.buscarRegistro(buscar);
        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane JSP = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel_JTable.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel_JTable.add(JSP);
        setColumnsWidth();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: mostrar(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

De esta forma se te verán las cabeceras, tendrás `int` en las columnas que devuelven `int` y hemos cambiado los "números mágicos" por variables.

Comment: Ok, he revisado el código y tenía un fallo al instanciar `registros`. Úsalo ahora que te tiene que funcionar. Borra los comentarios que sobran para limpiar un poco.

Comment: Respecto al tema del header en las columnas usa [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) en vez de [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html). `JPanel` no implementa el "column header" y `JScrollPane` sí.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49383/discussion-between-awes0mem4n-and-robert-gomez).